# grouping objects with .push then output to string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Very noobie question here but just can't wrap my dumb brain around this.

I have 2 arrays:

```
var catUri = [
  { catUri : "//test.com//test1" },
  { catUri : "//test.com//test2" }
];

var catKey = [
  { catKey : "test1" },
  { catKey : "test2" }
];
```

I'm trying join the arrays, then get the string from each object to create html like so...

```
<h2>Test</h2>
<ul>
  <li><a href="//test.com//test1" title="test1">test1</a></li>
  <li><a href="//test.com//test2" title="test2">test2</a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried a merge like this:

```
var merge = [];
merge.push(catUri, catKey);
```

Which returns:

```
[[Object { catKey="Test1"}, Object { catKey="Test2"}], [Object { catUri="//test.com//test1"}, Object { catUri="//test.com//test2"}]]
```

Here's where I start to get lost(if I'm not already lost)... When I try to get a string from the push object, I keep getting an undefined object.

```
$.each(merge, function(){
  var str = '<li><a href="' + this.catUri + '" title="' + this.catKey + '">' + this.catKey + '<\/a><\/li>';
  console.log(str);
});
```

Which returns:

```
<li><a href="undefined" title="undefined">undefined</a></li>
<li><a href="undefined" title="undefined">undefined</a></li>
```

Looping through a plain object returns my expected result.

```
$.each(catKey, function(){
  var str = '<li>' + this.catKey + '</li>';
  console.log(str);
});

<li>test1</li>
<li>test2</li>
```

I'm probably not merging these objects correctly. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var merge = [],
i = 0;
$.each(catUri,function(){
    merge.push({
        catUri: catUri[i].catUri,
        catKey: catKey[i].catKey
    });
    i++;
});
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        catUri: "//test.com//test1",
        catKey: "test1"
    },
    {
        catUri: "//test.com//test2",
        catKey: "test2"
    }
]
```

**JSFiddle Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/7RXjw/

Comment: Thanks for the help Mark. I was going a bit overboard on even having to group these in the first place. After hours of pain, it's still good to know how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

So, from your example I've inferred that `catUri` and `catKey` are associated by index, and you want to merge the element at each position from one to another.

```
var merge = $.map(catUri, function(value, index) {
   return $.extend(value, catKey[index]);
});
```

That will give you

```
[{catUri: '//test.com/test1', catKey: 'test1' }, {catUri: '//test.com/test2', catKey: 'test2'}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HackedByChinese/vm69c/

Comment: Nice, a more terse way of doing this... much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to merge these arrays? How about simple separate iteration?

```
for (var i = 0; i < catUri.length; i++) {
    var uri = catUri[i].catUri;
    var key = catKey[i].catKey;
    $("<li />").append($("<a />").attr({
        title : key,
        href : uri
    }).text(key)).appendTo("ul");
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Yya2m/

Comment: Thanks for the help VisioN.  Should have posted here way earlier. I've been over complicating this for hours...